# How should I stop users from modifying my data files?

Tags: c#, .net, security, file

I'm working on a project that is going to replace legacy software on our manufacturing floor. One of my concerns is that currently, config files, script caches, etc are all plain text, stored on the system that the user is using. A lot of this stuff is going to get pushed off to limit access network locations, but things like config files stay local. It's already been an issue with users thinking that they know what they're doing with the system, and modifying the config files. I don't want this happening any more in the new software. How should I prevent this? Encryption? Do some sort of signing/checksum with a database lookup? What kind of features does C#/.NET offer to help me out with this?

**UPDATE:** Just to address some things that were brought up in comments, every user on the manufacturing floor has admin access to the system they're working on. This isn't likely to change soon as most of the security comes from limiting access to folders on the network, web services, and databases. Permissions would be ideal, I agree, but I have to work in the environment that I'm provided. I plan to bring it up in a meeting that I have with IS to see if this is a possibility, but assume for now that this will be on a system where the user has full access.

Comment: Is this winforms or webforms?

Comment: It will be a WPF application.

Comment: ...Permissions...Didn't really think of that, but as it is right now, everyone on the manufacturing floor has admin access to the system they're logged in on, and I don't think that's going to change any time soon.

Answer (score 5):

This isn't a C# coding issue, it's a system configuration issue.  Set up the machine such that the users have normal (non-admin) accounts.  Set the file permissions on the config files you're worried about so that anyone (including your app running as current user) can read the config files, but only an admin can write the config files.  Finally, don't give the users the admin password. ;>

If your app needs to be able to write the the config files also, you'll have to add code to transition into admin mode within your app, preferably only around the write operation.

Comment: I'll have to talk to our IS department about this, I don't have the ability to take away permissions. I'd like for specific users to be able to log into and admin mode like you mentioned and be able to modify the config files, how complicated is this to do?

Comment: The code to enter admin mode is a bit tricky, but a web search or StackOverflow search should return you some examples.

Answer (score 4):

To prevent the average end-user from modifying config files by hand, you could simply sign the config file using the SHA of its contents concatenated with some secret factor known only by the program. This is obviously not a true or perfect secret, but it's enough to prevent simple tampering by end-users.

Basically (pseudo-code):

```
function isValidConfig(configPath, signaturePath) {
  return readFile(signaturePath) == SHA(readFile(configPath) + secret)
}

function writeConfig(contents, configPath, signaturePath) {
  writeFile(configPath, contents)
  writeFile(signaturePath, SHA(contents + secret))
}
```

Short of decompiling the program, they won't be able to tamper with the config. I assume you don't have l33t crax0rs on your manufacturing floor...

Comment: This is more of what I was thinking. Is there a way to make this a little more secure? There are a couple of people on the floor I can think of that have the potential to break this if they wanted to. Chances are very low that they would break it, but I'd like to do my best to prevent it.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a good job for a Digital Signature. A Digital signature will provide integrity and authentication of your data. Meaning the digital signature will detect if the data (config file) has been changed, and that the data originated from a trusted source. A digital signature is created by performing a hash of the data and then encrypting the hash with a private key from a public/private pair. The Application will decrypt the encrypted hash, calculate hash of the data, and compare the decrypted hash to the calculated hash. If the hashes match the data is valid. If they do not match the data has been altered.

.Net contains these functions in [DSACryptoServiceProvider.VerifyHash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dsacryptoserviceprovider.verifyhash.aspx)

Of course if you do not want to go through the hassle of creating a public/private key pair you could just go with a simple hash of the config file to make sure it hasn't been altered.

The really important question is; **what are you going to do when the application detects an altered config file?**

Are you going to have the application quit, lock out certain functions, send an e-mail to you, try to obtain a good copy of a config file? These actions are referred to as the penalty for failing the integrity check. Right now your application is not performing integrity checks on the config file, but when you add the check you will need to decide the best course of action for a failure.

Answer (score 1):

An option is for you to move as much as you can from the config file to either IsolatedStorage or even better to the database.  It would be highly unlikely that a typical user would know how to access them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep the files in some kind of structured storage, be it isolated storage, slightly encrypted ZIP file or something like our [SolFS](http://www.eldos.com/solfs/) virtual file system (also encrypted). The secondary benefit of having one file is that it can be copied for backup easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in local security but maybe you could use file system permissions to prevent use access to a given folder or file.

Then, if you application needs to access this file, you will have to launch your application with different windows account that has the right to modify your file.